# Idiomatic way to possibly compose a function

Tags: scala

I am building a value through a series of chaining function calls (all results are of type `B`):

```
val o: Option[String] = ...
val b: B = someFunc()
    .map(func1)
    .map(func2)
    .map(/* want to apply func3 here if o.isDefined)
```

Now, I have `func3: (B, String) => B` which I want to apply only if `o` is defined, and in that case I also want to pass it the value of the option as the second parameter. This would be equivalent to:

```
val tmp: B = someFunc()
    .map(func1)
    .map(func2)
val b = o.fold{b}{v => func3(tmp, v)}
```

But I wouldn't like to break the call chain. Any idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: I think you meant `o.fold{tmp}...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious simple but not elegant solution is the following:

```
val b = someFunc().map(func1).map(func2)
  .map( a => if( o.isDefined ) func3( a, v ) else a )
```

Here's an a bit modified version of the one you suggested:

```
val b = someFunc().map(func1).map(func2)
  .map( a => o.foldLeft( a )( func3 ) )
```